# Free online php pastebins that "interpret" your code?

Tags: php

I used to use:

http://codepad.viper-7.com

However it seems like it's down atm.  Are there any other php pastebins that "interpret" code?

EX. typing in this:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello, World!";
?>
```

Would print **Hello, World!**

Comment: [Codepad.org](http://codepad.org) is working now.

Comment: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Thanks boys, however Rafael's printed the literal "<br />" for 
printf("<br />");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to quickly test a php string, I always use the command line, like this:

```
php -r "var_dump((bool) null);"
php -r "var_dump((bool) '');"
php -r 'echo "Hello, World!";'
```

Protips©

Comment: Not sure why anyone downvoted this answer, I think it's really helpful even though it's an extension of the original question.